# How to disable/remove the "Create", "Write" operations for users in a group, but only on some views

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have a special user group who is allowed to create new `res.partner` instances, but only if they go through a series of steps with custom views.

On the other hand, they have restricted view possibilities on `res.partner`.

Thus in CRUD terminology, these users have the Create right.
On the other hand, I don't want to provide them general create rights, but only if the follow their partner wizard view.
Still, they have the Read right as well on `res.partner`, thus I would like to present them with a link to the tree view without a Create button.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 4):

In your case you want to hide create button from tree view.

May be this will help you...

```
<tree create="false">
....
</tree>
```

`create="flase"`, this will be hide your create button.

You can use this one in also your kanban view & form view.

Same way you can use `edit="false"` to hide your edit button, and also `delete="false"` for delete option.

```
<kanban create="false" edit="false">
....
</kanban>
```